# Can One Container use the file of another Container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-registry, docker-volume

Basically I have a main directory and Books Directory (General file structure, there's more but these are the important pieces). So when I fire a request from main to booksServer, it doesn't work because the node modules are missing.

That's because the node modules are inside the docker container at a specific path:  **'/usr/src/app'**

How can I have main.js see that books (service/container) does have the proper node packages inside this specific path?

I think I can use docker-compose, but I wanted to test it individually without docker-compose first.

```
**-Main Directory (Individual Service, has its own container)**
  -Initiator (Fires commands) 
  -DockerFile

**-Books Directory (Individual Service, has its own container)**
  -Stubs
     -BooksStub.js (NEED THIS!, but it won't work because needs npm modules which is located in its container @/usr/src/app. How can I access the nodemodules that it's using?)

  -booksServer.js
  -Package*.json (lock and package.json)
  -DockerFile
```

Inside the

**Error:**

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:800
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'grpc'
```

**Books Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:12.14.0
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 30043
CMD ["node", "booksServer.js"]
```

**Main DockerFile**

```
FROM node:12.14.0
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 4555
CMD ["node", "main.js"]
```

Comment: yeah create a volume and then map it to the two dockers and set their mode if you want read only

Answer (score 0):

Using volume it is possible to share files from one container to another container.

- Create a volume to share between two Docker containers:

  docker volume create --name volume_name
- Create container_first with volume

  docker run -it --name=container_first -v volume_name:/volume  image_name
- Create container_second which will share files with container_first

  docker run -it --name=container_second --volumes-from container_first image_name